# Why the result of querying time series returned blank in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I tried to query out `root.turbine.d2.s1` time series in Apache IoTDB using `show timeseries root.turbine` command, but the result returned blank and no timeseries returned. Why can't I find this time series in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.**` after the command you use now to query certain time series of Apache IoTDB. Therefore, the complete command should be `show time series root.turbine.**`.